# Error installing pg, requires Ruby version >= 2.2 even if ruby is >=2.2

Tags: ruby

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
$ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby
$ which gem
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/gem
$ sudo gem install pg
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    pg requires Ruby version >= 2.2.
```

Error installing pg, requires Ruby version >= 2.2 even if ruby is >=2.2.

Comment: The tl;dr here is: If you're using `sudo` with `rvm`, then in 99.9% of cases you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Try running `sudo ruby --version` and you'll see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using RVM, it is necessary for some environment variables to be loaded to RVM (and RVM-installed Rubies) to find its code.

When running your `gem install` command with `sudo` however, sudo will reset your `$PATH` and unset the required environment variables before executing the `gem` command with the sanitized `$PATH`. With that, you will likely use your system ruby rather than your RVM-installed ruby.

In general, you should not use `sudo` to install Rubies or any gems when using RVM. Instead, you generally can and should just use your normal user.

If you do have to use `sudo` with RVM for some reason, there is a special `rvmsudo` command which retains your RVM environment in the evaluated context. See https://rvm.io/integration/sudo for details. However, as written above, you should try to avoid using this!